# ag-grid apply style to Total footer

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using `groupIncludeTotalFooter` to display footer. I was able to change footer text using `footerValueGetter`.

However i am trying to find a better way to apply some styles to the Total footer row.

Currently I am doing some CSS selection as follows. Wanted to know if this is the only way or there is better way.

```
.my-component .ag-row-footer {
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: What's your definition of better? For styling common ag-grid components I opt for css module like what you posted in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this programatically by leveraging the Grid Callback method `getRowStyle`:

```
gridOptions = {
    getRowStyle: (params) => {
      if (params.node.footer) {
        return { fontWeight: 'bold' };
      }
    },
}
```

This will make the footer bold, as shown in the [following example](https://plnkr.co/edit/S7JspJUj8S8tLqgl)

There are other ways of achieving this programatically, if you need more flexibility, in the documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/